# how can i copy database from main bundle to application folder at runtime?

Tags: ios

i use a sqlite database in iOS apps which name is testSqlite.sqlite. i want to copy it to application folder. but the file is not copy to the desire location. i also add my source code to it. please help

```
 NSString *docsDir;
 NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths [0];

NSString *backupPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testSqlite" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSLog(@"backup is %@ ",backupPath);
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: docsDir]) {
    if (backupPath) {
        BOOL copiedBackup = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:backupPath toPath:docsDir error:nil];
        if (!copiedBackup) {
            // copying backup db failed, bail
            NSLog(@"Copying backup db failed");
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"\n\ndatabase created");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the NSLog output

Answer (score 1):

Apple recommends using URL´s and the following code works in my App:

```
NSString *docDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *filePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testSqlite.sqlite"];

NSURL *fileDocURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProductInventory.plist"]];
NSURL *newFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSLog(@"fileDocURL: %@, newFileURL: %@", fileDocURL, newFileURL);

NSError __autoreleasing *error;
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:fileDocURL toURL:newFileURL error:&error];
if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Transaction file was copied");
        // Delete the old file
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:fileDocURL error:nil];
} else {
        NSLog(@"NO transaction file to copy, Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: this is for nsurl. but i need for it to copy to directory document folder.thanks for comment @Hannes Sverrisson

Comment: @user3903633 You use URL´s for copying files between folders. Try, the code!

Comment: @user3903633 You should accept answers to your questions here or people may stop answering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for copy main bundle to document directory folder for runtime.

```
  NSString *pathsToReources = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *yourOriginalDatabasePath = [pathsToReources stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"lunchDB.sqlite"];

    NSArray *pathsToDocuments = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathsToDocuments objectAtIndex: 0];

        NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"lunchDB.sqlite"];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath: dbPath]) {

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath: yourOriginalDatabasePath toPath: dbPath error: NULL] != YES)

    NSAssert2(0, @"Fail to copy database from %@ to %@", yourOriginalDatabasePath, dbPath);

    }
```

replace your file name "lunchDB.sqlite" here.
Thanks.

Comment: thanks all for comment. i use those solution and solve my problem. again thaks for comment